# Write a function in R to group factor levels by frequency, then keep the 2 largest categories and pool the rest in "other"

Tags: r, function, group-by

I would like to write a function in R that takes a single factor variable and a parameter n as inputs, computes the number of cases per category in the factor variable, and only keeps those n categories with the most number of cases and pools all other categories into a category "other." This function must be applied to  multiple variables, keeping the 2 largest categories for each variable and pooling all other categories in each variable into a category "other."

Example:

```
var1 <- c("square", "square", "square", "circle", "square", "square", "circle",
"square", "circle", "circle", "circle", "circle", "square", "circle", "triangle", "circle", "circle", "rectangle")

var2 <- c("orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "blue", "orange", "blue",
"blue", "orange", "blue", "blue", "blue", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "green", "purple")

df <- data.frame(var1, var2)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello Marc-Marijn. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post.  The more specific you can make your question and include some data & code that you wrote, the more likely you are to receive a helpful answer.

Comment: I find it unclear what the function is supposed to do exactly. It would help if you showed us how the function should be called (with what parameters) and what the expected output looks like. At the moment, your code has nothing to do with the functionality you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forcats::fct_lump_n()` exists for precisely this:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(fct_lump_n, 2)

     var1   var2
1  square orange
2  square orange
3  square orange
4  circle orange
5  square   blue
6  square orange
7  circle   blue
8  square   blue
9  circle orange
10 circle   blue
11 circle   blue
12 circle   blue
13 square orange
14 circle orange
15  Other orange
16 circle orange
17 circle  Other
18  Other  Other
```

Comment: Thank you! With a little editing I was able to make it into a function!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `data.table`. There is probably a more elegant way to do it but it seems to work

```r
library(data.table)

myfunc <- function(x, n = 10){

  xvar <- data.table::as.data.table('x' = x)
  dt <- xvar[,.('count' = .N), by = "x"][order(-get('count'))]

  dt[, "category" := as.character(get("x"))]
  dt[, 'rk' := (seq_len(.N)<=n)]
  dt[!get('rk'), c('category') := "other"]

  dt <- merge(xvar,dt, by = "x")

  return(dt$category)
}
```

I coerce your example dataframe as a `data.table` object

```r
var1 <- c("square", "square", "square", "circle", "square", "square", "circle",
          "square", "circle", "circle", "circle", "circle", "square", "circle", "triangle", "circle", "circle", "rectangle")

var2 <- c("orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "blue", "orange", "blue",
          "blue", "orange", "blue", "blue", "blue", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "green", "purple")

df <- data.frame(var1, var2)

df2 <- as.data.table(df)
```

Then, the call is quite easy:

```r
df2[,lapply(.SD, myfunc, n = 3)]

     var1   var2
 1:   circle   blue
 2:   circle   blue
 3:   circle   blue
 4:   circle   blue
 5:   circle   blue
 6:   circle   blue
 7:   circle  green
 8:   circle orange
 9:   circle orange
10:    other orange
11:   square orange
12:   square orange
13:   square orange
14:   square orange
15:   square orange
16:   square orange
17:   square orange
18: triangle  other
```

`data.table` object is a special `data.frame` thus you don't need to coerce it back to data.frame class

Comment: Thank you @linog, I have edited the post. Would this suffice? Also, is there an option to keep the data type as a dataframe?

Comment: I edited my answer. That's not the most elegant solution possible but it should do the trick