# can someone help me out by turning this code into a function x? it does not seem to work for me

Tags: r, function

### Turn the attributes into characters in order to manipulate them

```
crunchbase2015$category_list <- as.character(crunchbase2015$category_list)
crunchbase2015$country_code <- as.character(crunchbase2015$country_code)
crunchbase2015$region <- as.character(crunchbase2015$region)
```

### Change the categories with the 10 most mentions into "other" within the attributes

```
crunchbase2015$category_list[
  which(!crunchbase2015$category_list %in%
  names(rev(sort(table(crunchbase2015$category_list)))[1:10]))] <- "Other"

crunchbase2015$country_code[
  which(!crunchbase2015$country_code %in%
  names(rev(sort(table(crunchbase2015$country_code)))[1:10]))] <- "Other"

crunchbase2015$region[
  which(!crunchbase2015$region %in%
  names(rev(sort(table(crunchbase2015$region)))[1:10]))] <- "Other"
```

### Change the attributes back to factors

```
crunchbase2015$category_list <- as.factor(crunchbase2015$category_list)
crunchbase2015$country_code <- as.factor(crunchbase2015$country_code)
crunchbase2015$region <- as.factor(crunchbase2015$region)
```

### Data

```
    X                        name category_list funding_total_usd    status country_code        region funding_rounds
1   2                    :Qounter         Other            700000 operating          USA         Other              2
2   4                     0-6.com   Curated Web           2000000 operating          CHN         Other              1
3   7      Ondine Biomedical Inc. Biotechnology            762851 operating          CAN         Other              2
4   8                      H2O.ai     Analytics          33600000 operating          USA   SF Bay Area              4
5   9                    One Inc.        Mobile           1150050 operating          USA   SF Bay Area              3
6  10                 1,2,3 Listo    E-Commerce             40000 operating        Other         Other              1
7  14               1-800-DOCTORS         Other           1750000 operating          USA         Other              1
8  15 1-800-PublicRelations, Inc.         Other           6000000 operating          USA New York City              1
9  16                1 Mainstream          Apps           5000000  acquired          USA   SF Bay Area              1
10 17                     1 of 99         Other            100000 operating          USA   SF Bay Area              1
11 18                 10-20 Media    E-Commerce           2050000 operating          USA         Other              4
12 19             10 Minutes With         Other           4400000 operating          GBR        London              2
13 20                  1000 Corks         Other             40000 operating          USA         Other              1
14 21                1000 Markets         Other            500000  acquired          USA       Seattle              1
15 24                1000memories   Curated Web           2535000  acquired          USA   SF Bay Area              2
16 25             1000museums.com   Curated Web           6795451 operating          USA         Other              9
17 26                     ZenChef         Other          10661773 operating          FRA         Other              5
18 27          1001pharmacies.com         Other           8900000 operating          FRA         Other              1
19 28                     1006.tv         Other          10000000 operating          CHN         Other              3
20 31                       Redox   Health Care           4000000 operating          USA         Other              2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write a function in R to group factor levels by frequency, then keep the 2 largest categories and pool the rest in "other"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099087/write-a-function-in-r-to-group-factor-levels-by-frequency-then-keep-the-2-large)

Comment: The lump function doesn't work for me!

Comment: Perhaps you could share a snippet of your data?

Comment: How do i do that?  @stefan

Comment: Type `dput(crunchbase2015)` in the console and paste the resulting output in your post. However, as your data is probably large and your code uses only three columns e.g.`dput(crunchbase2015[1:20, c("category_list", "country_code", "region")]` gives the first twenty rows for the three columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Using `n = 3` for the example data I simply put your code into a function `lumpy`. I also added the solution via `forcats::fct_lump`. Results are somewhat differnt because of ties. Your code as well as `lumpy` simply selects alphabetically, while `forcats::fct_lump` offers variuos options using `ties.method`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# Original dataset
crunchbase2015 %>%
  select_at(vars("category_list", "region", "country_code")) %>% 
  str()
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ category_list: Factor w/ 8 levels "Analytics","Apps",..: 8 4 3 1 7 5 8 8 2 8 ...
#>  $ region       : Factor w/ 5 levels "London","New York City",..: 3 3 3 5 5 3 3 2 5 5 ...
#>  $ country_code : Factor w/ 6 levels "CAN","CHN","FRA",..: 6 2 1 6 6 5 6 6 6 6 ...

# Using simple function
lumpy <- function(f, n, other_level = "Other") {
  f <- as.character(f)
  f[which(!f %in% names(rev(sort(table(f)))[1:n]))] <- other_level
  as.factor(f)
}

crunchbase2015 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("category_list", "region", "country_code"), ~ lumpy(.x, n = 3)) %>% 
  select_at(vars("category_list", "region", "country_code")) %>% 
  str()
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ category_list: Factor w/ 3 levels "Curated Web",..: 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 ...
#>  $ region       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Other","Seattle",..: 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 3 3 ...
#>  $ country_code : Factor w/ 4 levels "CHN","FRA","Other",..: 4 1 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 ...

# Using fct.lump with ties.method = "first
crunchbase2015 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("category_list", "region", "country_code"), ~ forcats::fct_lump(.x, n = 3, other_level = "Other", ties.method = "last")) %>% 
  select_at(vars("category_list", "region", "country_code")) %>% 
  str()
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ category_list: Factor w/ 3 levels "Curated Web",..: 3 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 ...
#>  $ region       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Seattle","SF Bay Area",..: 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 ...
#>  $ country_code : Factor w/ 4 levels "CHN","FRA","USA",..: 3 1 4 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>